# Хеширование пароля в Yii

Tags: php, yii2

Подскажите, как сравнивать хешированный пароль в БД и хешированный пароль, который ввёл юзер в поле?
Ведь сохраняем мы один хэш, а при вводе пользователем пароля создаётся уже совсем другой. Перерыл много сайтов, но так и не понял суть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добрый вечер.
В yii2 есть специальный метод для этого, [yii\base\Security::validatePassword()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-security#validatePassword()-detail)

Проверять так

```
Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($password, $password_hash)
```

Comment: То есть $password - это пароль из бд, а $password_hash - это пароль введённый пользователем и захешированный?

Comment: Я уже проверил. Наоборот. $password - это пароль из поля, а $password_hash - это хэш из бд